# Unknown Facebook Payment error within our Facebook Canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas, facebook-payments, facebook-payment-dialog

I'm not sure when and how, but I can see in our data that some of our users receiving the following error while at FB payment dialog: "Dialog \"pay\" is trying to run more than once."

I was trying to search all over for this issue but can't find it anywhere.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: How are you initiating the pay dialog?

Comment: FB.ui({
     method:'pay',
     action: 'purchaseItem',
  product: filePath// link to product
  quantity: 1
  
 },
 pCallBack);